# RKHSs containing constant functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is the reproducing kernel Hilbert space on a space $X$ with reproducing kernel $K$.  If, say, $K - c$ is a positive definite kernel for some $c>0$ then $H$ contains the constant functions on $X$.  But this condition is not necessarily easy to verify.

Are there other known sufficient conditions that imply that a reproducing kernel Hilbert space on a space $X$ contains the constant functions?  In particular I'm interested in the case in which $X$ is a compact metric space and $K(x,y) = e^{-d(x,y)}$.  (This kernel is not necessarily positive definite; I'm interested in those $X$ for which it is.)  Certain special cases, like subsets of Euclidean space or spheres, I can handle with Fourier analysis via the above condition, but the more general case is unclear.

Comment: Your edits appeared after I posted my answer, but I don't think you want $\delta_{xy}$ in the condition you give, rather you subtract off the kernel that is identically $1$ on $X\times X$.  Also, for most of the kernels I'm familiar with this condition is not so hard to check; do you have a particular kernel that you're looking at?


Comment: Mike: You're right, I was sloppy about which basis I was thinking about.  I'll also add in the specific kernel I'm interested in.

Comment: There is another condition in terms of the geometry of the embedding $X\to H$ via $e:x\to k_x$ (assuming the normalization $k(x,x)\equiv 1$), though I'm not sure it's any easier to check: The space $H$ contains the constant functions if and only if the image of $X$ under $e$ lies in an affine hyperplane of $H$. (If $w\in H$ is constant on $X$, then the $k_x$'s lie in an affine hyperplane orthogonal to $w$, and conversely.) Though maybe this is the conclusion you want rather than a condition you want to check...

Comment: Mike: Your guess is correct --- this is actually the conclusion I want.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. A (fairly standard) fact about RKHS's is that a function $f:X\to \mathbb C$ belongs to the RKHS (with kernel $k$) if and only if there is a $c>0$ such that the Hermitian kernel
$$
k(x,y) -c^2f(x)\overline{f(y)}
$$
is positive semidefinite; the norm of $f$ is then equal to $1/c$ for the best possible $c$. Thus the constants belong to the RKHS if and only if
$$
k(x,y)-c^2
$$
is positive semidefinite for some positive $c$.

Comment: Thanks for that.  As you noted, I added an edit while you were writing your answer to point out that I know this condition, but I wasn't positive that it was necessary as well as sufficient.

Comment: Do you know if this fact applies to real valued RKHSs too? Also, do you know where I might find a reference for this?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Theorem 4.15 here: https://www.math.uh.edu/~vern/rkhs.pdf